# Centos 6 64bit enable my.cnf

Tags: mysql, centos, my.cnf, centos6

Can someone please tell me how to enable `my.cnf` options in CentOS 6?

I have all the expected `.cnf` files in `/usr/share/mysql` but they simply don't work.

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld --help --verbose
Usage: /etc/init.d/mysqld {start|stop|status|restart|condrestart|try-restart|reload|force-reload}
```

Comment: Just `/etc/init.d/mysqld start`. Options go in `/etc/my.cnf`.

Comment: This /etc/init.d/mysqld --help --verbose normally shows you you mysql options but not in my case

Comment: I think you are confusing the launcher script with mysql itsef. Try `mysql --help --verbose`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to place the my.cnf file in /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Comment: /etc/my.cnf should be an allowed location and searched by default. I would guess SELinux is configured to allow only /etc/mysql/my.cnf. Moving it into the location SELinux wants is one way to solve this problem. You could also edit the SELinux policy file for MySQL, or else disable SELinux (many sites opt for the latter).

Answer (score 2):

Default location is /etc/my.cnf as far as I'm aware of. Maybe you should try and copy them over there and restart?

Comment: Tried it. Makes no difference

Answer (score 2):

`my.cnf` should be placed in `/etc/` like `/etc/my.cnf`

Comment: The solution was to place the my.cnf file in /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Answer (score 0):

the init.d script mysqld relais on the script in /usr/bin/my_print_defaults ..

this scripts takes as first input the "domain", e.g. mysqld_safe oder mysqld and outputs the config ..

this script merges the .cnf files from /etc/mysq/my.cnf + /etc/my.cnf + ~/.my.cnf together and outputs key=value pairs in the form of ..

```
]# /usr/bin/my_print_defaults mysqld
--datadir=/var/lib/mysql
--socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
--user=mysql
--symbolic-links=0
```

so placing the .cnf files in /usr/share/mysql might be wrong ..